# Reverting a git merge, then later merging some of the reverted commits

Tags: git, branch, git-merge, branching-and-merging, git-revert

Suppose the following git history (in chronological order):

```
master    [I]------------------------[M2]---[MG]---[RV]---[MG2]
dev         \---[D1]----------[D2]----------/              /
release            \---[R1]-------------------------------/
```

- The repo starts with an initial commit `I`.
- A dev branch is created with one new commit `D1`.
- A release branch is branched off of dev with a new commit `R1`.
- A new commit is added to the dev branch (`D2`).
- A new commit is added to the master branch (`M2`).
- dev is merged into master (`MG`)
- Uh oh! we didn't mean to do that... we revert the merge commit `RV` with `-m 1` to specify that master should be considered the mainline
- We had meant to merge release into master, so we do that now (`MG2`)

Oh no! Now the changes introduced in `D1` are not present on master. I want them to be included (but I don't want `D2`'s changes to be present).
So my questions are:

1. Assuming that I've just merged dev to master (`MG`), is there a command that I can use in place of `git revert` so that when I merge release into master I'll still have the changes from `D1`?
2. Suppose I've already gone ahead with a merge from dev into master and a revert, is there a command I can use in place of `git merge` so that when I merge release into master I'll still have the changes from `D1`?

I'm aware that I could achieve this by doing a `git reset --hard M2` on the master branch, but I want to avoid rewriting history if at all possible. It would also be great if a solution accounted for the possibility that additional "good" commits were added to the master branch between `MG` and `RV` or between `RV` and `MG2`.

Comment: Are you sure the changes in D1 are not in master? From your history it seems R1 contains the changes in D1, which should therefore be in MG2.

Comment: I doubted myself at first too, but the git docs have a note about the issue here:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert#git-revert---mainlineparent-number:
"Reverting a merge commit declares that you will never want the tree changes brought in by the merge. As a result, later merges will only bring in tree changes introduced by commits that are not ancestors of the previously reverted merge."

Comment: The docs there actually link to a note by Linus about the issue, so my answer may be found there:
https://git-scm.com/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.html

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt) (search for ADDENDUM) is to recreate an alternative to `D1` (`D1'` below), so that its content is not ignored by later merges:

```
git checkout dev
git rebase --no-ff I
```

This should result in:

```
dev         /---[D1']---------[D2']
master    [I]------------------------[M2]---[MG]---[RV]---[MG2]
            \---[D1]----------[D2]----------/              /
release            \---[R1]-------------------------------/
```

You also need to recreate your `release` branch so that it starts at `D1'`, then merge that to master:

```
git checkout release
git rebase D1' 
git checkout master
git merge release
```

Result:

```
release             /---[R1']---------------------------------\
dev         /---[D1']---------[D2']                            \
master    [I]------------------------[M2]---[MG]--[RV]--[MG2]--[MG3]
            \---[D1]----------[D2]----------/            /
                   \---[R1]-----------------------------/
```

Of course, if you've not pushed `MG2`, it might be a good idea to clean up before. This kind of history could easily confuse people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use git cherry-pick to resolved your mistakes > https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick